# DateTime.UtcNow is auto converted to local by .net entity framework / postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, datetime, entity-framework-core

I am storing all my DateTimes as UTC in the database, using `DateTime.UtcNow`. They are storing well in this format: `2023-08-03 13:54:15.474570 +00:00`
However, when I am retrieving data from the database using a Linq command, for example:
`await _context.SomeEntity.ToListAsync()`.
I am getting dates in local format like this: `2023-08-03T15:54:15.47457+02:00` which is in my local time.

The big deal is that when the entity is updated (other values than the datetime), the new wrong datetime is stored back in the database.

I am using the following versions:

.Net 7.0

Postgres packages 7.0.4

**Already tried to solve the issue:**

1- Change all properties from DateTime to DateTimeOffset.

2- Apply .UseNodaTime() to db options like that: `options.UseNpgsql(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),  x => x.UseNodaTime());`.

3- Specify the kind before saving the value using `DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Utc)`. I guess I must had to do that on getting the values not before saving, but that is kind of impossible solution to apply on everywhere I get values from the db.

Comment: What is the data type in Postgres for the timestamp fields?

Comment: My guess is that your column type is `timestamp [ (p) ] with time zone`, and that npgsql automatically convert UTC DateTimes to local for such a column type.

Comment: Totally correct, I went into the database and changed the column type from (timestamp with time zone, to without time zone) so that solved the problem.
Any suggestions how to do that from model builder in dbcontext?

Comment: You have now created another problem `select '2023-08-03 13:54:15.474570 +00:00'::timestamp; 2023-08-03 13:54:15.47457`, an un-anchored timestamp. Read [Time stamps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).

Comment: If you select current_time the result is correct?

Answer (score -1):

You are experiencing an issue with Entity Framework Core, which by default changes DateTime objects to the system's local time unless specified as UTC.

You can solve this issue in two ways:

1. Overriding SaveChanges in your DbContext: Overriding `SaveChanges` and `SaveChangesAsync` methods in your DbContext allows you to manually convert all DateTime objects to UTC before they are saved. This approach ensures all DateTime properties are saved in UTC.

```cs
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    UpdateDates();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
{
    UpdateDates();
    return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
}

private void UpdateDates()
{
    var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
    .Where(e => e.Entity is SomeEntity && 
        (e.State == EntityState.Added || e.State == EntityState.Modified));

    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            ((SomeEntity)entity.Entity).CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        ((SomeEntity)entity.Entity).ModificationDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }
}
```

2. Using Value Conversion in EF Core: With Value Conversion, you can specify how EF Core should convert between the provider type and the .NET type. This can be done for specific properties or all DateTime properties of all entities.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        var dateTimeProperties = entityType.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime) || p.ClrType == typeof(DateTime?));

        foreach (var property in dateTimeProperties)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity(entityType.Name).Property(property.Name)
                .HasConversion(
                    v => v, 
                    v => DateTime.SpecifyKind(v, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        }
    }
}
```

Both methods ensure DateTime values are read as UTC. If you deal with dates in different time zones, you might consider storing them as DateTimeOffset.

Comment: I downvoted this because the first sentence isn't true. At least not for EF core. It seems specific to the postrgreSql query provider. It's better to add that so as no to sidetrack other EF users. Also, what is "converted" in the first example?